# How to merge multiple columns from different dataframes with different columns names in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have two datasets that show Employment by ID and one that shows manager approvals for work, neither one has identical column names but have similar values for some columns. I need to merge in multiple columns from the first dataset into the second and have them read in a employees ID by their name.

DF1: All Employment

```
ID     Emp_Name          Job            Status     Team 
101    Josh A.       Sales Advisor      Active     Sales
102    Sarah B.      Sales Advisor      Termed     Sales 
103    Michael C.    Tech Support       Active     Tech 
104    Fred D.       Tech Support       Termed     Tech
.
.
.  
823   Frank O.       Financial Advisor  Termed    Finance
```

DF2: Focuses on the terminated IDs

```
Termed_Name       Manager_Name    Manager_ID 
 Sarah B.            Mary S.         156
 Fred D.             John D.         164
  Paul M.
Frank O.            Gary H.         532
```

Desired DF:

```
Manager_Name  Manager_ID  Termed_Name   ID  
 Mary S.         156      Sarah B.     102
 John D.         164      Fred D.      104
   NA             NA      Paul M.      NA
 .
 .
 .
 Gary H.          532     Frank O.     823
```

I have tried using `pd.concat` and `pd.merge` but have no luck so far with getting the result I want.

Comment: are three empty rows as a result of the merge also needed?

Comment: The three dots is to express continuation but within the data their are almost filly empty rows

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'ID': [101, 102, 103, 104, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 823],
     'Emp_Name': ['Josh A.', 'Sarah B.', 'Michael C.', 'Fred D.', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'Frank O.'],
     'Job': ['Sales Advisor', 'Sales Advisor', 'Tech Support', 'Tech Support', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
             'Financial Advisor'],
     'Status': ['Active', 'Termed', 'Active', 'Termed', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'Termed'],
     'Team': ['Sales', 'Sales', 'Tech', 'Tech', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'Finance']
     })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Termed_Name': ['Sarah B.', 'Fred D.', 'Paul M.', 'Frank O.'],
    'Manager_Name': ['Mary S.', 'John D.', np.nan, 'Gary H.'],
    'Manager_ID': [156, 164, np.nan, 532]})


df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='Emp_Name', right_on='Termed_Name', how='right')[['Manager_Name', 'Manager_ID', 'Termed_Name', 'ID']]
print(df3)
```

Here I've done a right side merge.

```
  Manager_Name  Manager_ID Termed_Name     ID
0      Mary S.       156.0    Sarah B.  102.0
1      John D.       164.0     Fred D.  104.0
2          NaN         NaN     Paul M.    NaN
3      Gary H.       532.0    Frank O.  823.0
```

If you need those empty lines, then I can do it, but they will be at the end:

```
df4 = pd.concat([df1[df1.isnull().all(axis=1)], df3]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)[['Manager_Name', 'Manager_ID', 'Termed_Name', 'ID']]

print(df4)
```

Output

```
  Manager_Name  Manager_ID Termed_Name     ID
0      Mary S.       156.0    Sarah B.  102.0
1      John D.       164.0     Fred D.  104.0
2          NaN         NaN     Paul M.    NaN
3      Gary H.       532.0    Frank O.  823.0
4          NaN         NaN         NaN    NaN
5          NaN         NaN         NaN    NaN
6          NaN         NaN         NaN    NaN
```